# Making Expo/React Native ignore a specific module

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

My Expo app references a locally developed module that has functions that use nodejs modules “fs” and “os”, however those functions are never called in my app, when I try to run my app, the Expo bundler complains that the modules cannot be resolved, how can I make Expo/RN ignore them (ignoring is fine since the app won’t use these functions anyway)